Amount of something used

The remaining water  in the jug on the left should be called:
A. used
B. leftover
C. consumed
D. ???
I think the word USED should be for the water which was in the jug on the right, but now it is not available in the jug as can be seen on the left.

If the left-hand jug was originally as full as the right-hand one, and someone has filled several glasses from it which people have drunk from, that water has been used or consumed.
However, the question asks about the water remaining in the jug. The only appropriate term for that is leftover.
